# android video apply filter

Tags: android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview, encoder

I have a video created with MediaCodec from camera preview. 
Now I  want to edit that video, to apply a filter (white/black) and save to another file.
I read about DecodeEditEncodeTest.java from CTS tests and tried to adapt to my problem, but I noticed that onFrameAvailable from outputSurface is never called.
The only difference from example that I read video data using  MediaExtractor.

In log I receive: ": EGL_BAD_SURFACE" at swapbuffers.

Please advise me what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I didn't call method to inputSurface, makeCurrent